# When I connected my iPhone to a MacBook, the Finder doesn't show the app I created

Tags: ios

I found that I can put a file in my iPhone application using Finder on the latest version of MacOS.
But the application I created is not showing up in the Finder.

Only I can see the applications I have installed from the App Store.
What should I do to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the UIFileSharingEnabled key to your app’s Info.plist file
2. Set the value of the key to YES